# "Go to" option in jquery pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Created pagination in jquery,

Now I am trying to have it more user-friendly by adding input box **Go To** (See the top of the resulted snippet). I am not able to decide how would it be done? I need on <kbd>onKeyPress</kbd> (that means no submit button for it):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var totalRows = $('#tblData').find('tbody tr:has(td)').length;
  var recordPerPage = 18;
  var totalPages = Math.ceil(totalRows / recordPerPage);
  var $pages = $('<div id="pages"></div>');
  for (i = 0; i < totalPages; i++) {
    $('<span class="pageNumber">&nbsp;' + (i + 1) + '</span>').appendTo($pages);
  }
  $pages.appendTo('#tblData');

  $('.pageNumber').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).addClass('focus');
    },
    function() {
      $(this).removeClass('focus');
    }
  );

  $('table').find('tbody tr:has(td)').hide();
  var tr = $('table tbody tr:has(td)');
  for (var i = 0; i <= recordPerPage - 1; i++) {
    $(tr[i]).show();
  }
  $('span').click(function(event) {
    $('#tblData').find('tbody tr:has(td)').hide();
    var nBegin = ($(this).text() - 1) * recordPerPage;
    var nEnd = $(this).text() * recordPerPage - 1;
    for (var i = nBegin; i <= nEnd; i++) {
      $(tr[i]).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.focus {
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#pages {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.pageNumber {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>KBC</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Go to.." />
    <table id="tblData" class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="alert alert-info"><label class="control-label">Question 1</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Question</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">मुनि हिंसा आदि पापों का त्याग कितनी कोटि से करता है  ?</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Option A</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">6</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Option B</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">7</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Option C</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">8</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Option D</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">9</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Right Answer</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">D</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="2"><a href="http://localhost/bol25kids/admin_question.php?question=174906"><button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> &nbsp; Alter this question
        </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
 <tr rowspan="2"><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
        <tr>
     <td colspan="2" class="alert alert-info"><label class="control-label">Question 2</label></td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Question</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">'अभिमान  से बंधने वाला कौनसा पाप है  ? </label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option A</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">क्रोध </label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option B</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">मान</label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option C</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">माया </label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option D</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">लोभ</label></td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Right Answer</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">B</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td></td>
        <td colspan="2"><a href="http://localhost/bol25kids/admin_question.php?question=174806"><button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> &nbsp; Alter this question
        </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
 <tr rowspan="2"><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
        <tr>
     <td colspan="2" class="alert alert-info"><label class="control-label">Question 3</label></td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Question</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">तिर्यञ्च जीवों के दण्डक कितने है  ?</label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option A</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">7</label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option B</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">8</label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option C</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">9</label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option D</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">10</label></td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Right Answer</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">C</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td></td>
        <td colspan="2"><a href="http://localhost/bol25kids/admin_question.php?question=174706"><button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> &nbsp; Alter this question
        </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
 <tr rowspan="2"><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
        <tr>
 <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Question</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">नाग कुमार का दण्डक कौनसा है  ?</label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option A</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">तीसरा </label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option B</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">चौथा</label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option C</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">पांचवां</label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option D</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">छठा </label></td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Right Answer</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">A</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td></td>
        <td colspan="2"><a href="http://localhost/bol25kids/admin_question.php?question=174606"><button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> &nbsp; Alter this question
        </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Now I am trying to have it more user-friendly by adding input box **Go To** (See the top of the resulted snippet). I am not able to decide how would it be done? I need on <kbd>onKeyPress</kbd> (that means no submit button for it).

Comment: if keyCode is 13 than go... Unclear part is how does what is enter match the button you want to click? If you add a data attribute with the number, it would be easy to look up....

Comment: **The above snippet is just an example, there are 150 pages with 4 questions in reality**. For the above example if `keyCode` is 13 then it should do nothing...

Comment: 13 is the enter key

Comment: So pull out the function that is in `$('span').click(function(event) ` so you can pass in a number to it and reuse the code. Or you can just select the span and fire the click event on it....

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `keypress` event listener to the `input` and if `event.which` is equal to `13` (enter), you can execute a function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var numOfPages = 2;
  var totalRows = $('#tblData').find('tbody tr:has(td)').length;
  var recordPerPage = 18;
  var totalPages = Math.ceil(totalRows / recordPerPage);
  var $pages = $('<div id="pages"></div>');
  for (i = 0; i < totalPages; i++) {
    $('<span class="pageNumber">&nbsp;' + (i + 1) + '</span>').appendTo($pages);
  }
  $pages.appendTo('#tblData');
  
  $('#goTo').keypress(function(e){
     var value = parseInt($(this).val());
     if(e.which==13&&!isNaN(value)&&value>0&&value<=numOfPages){
       alert("Going to "+value+"...!")
       $('.pageNumber')[value-1].click();
     }
  });

  $('.pageNumber').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).addClass('focus');
    },
    function() {
      $(this).removeClass('focus');
    }
  );

  $('table').find('tbody tr:has(td)').hide();
  var tr = $('table tbody tr:has(td)');
  for (var i = 0; i <= recordPerPage - 1; i++) {
    $(tr[i]).show();
  }
  $('span').click(function(event) {
    $('#tblData').find('tbody tr:has(td)').hide();
    var nBegin = ($(this).text() - 1) * recordPerPage;
    var nEnd = $(this).text() * recordPerPage - 1;
    for (var i = nBegin; i <= nEnd; i++) {
      $(tr[i]).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.focus {
  background-color: green;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#pages {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.pageNumber {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>KBC</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="number" placeholder="Go to.." id="goTo"/>
    <table id="tblData" class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="alert alert-info"><label class="control-label">Question 1</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Question</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">मुनि हिंसा आदि पापों का त्याग कितनी कोटि से करता है  ?</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Option A</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">6</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Option B</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">7</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Option C</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">8</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Option D</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">9</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Right Answer</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">D</label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="2"><a href="http://localhost/bol25kids/admin_question.php?question=174906"><button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> &nbsp; Alter this question
        </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
 <tr rowspan="2"><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
        <tr>
     <td colspan="2" class="alert alert-info"><label class="control-label">Question 2</label></td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Question</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">'अभिमान  से बंधने वाला कौनसा पाप है  ? </label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option A</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">क्रोध </label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option B</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">मान</label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option C</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">माया </label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option D</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">लोभ</label></td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Right Answer</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">B</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td></td>
        <td colspan="2"><a href="http://localhost/bol25kids/admin_question.php?question=174806"><button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> &nbsp; Alter this question
        </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
 <tr rowspan="2"><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
        <tr>
     <td colspan="2" class="alert alert-info"><label class="control-label">Question 3</label></td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Question</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">तिर्यञ्च जीवों के दण्डक कितने है  ?</label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option A</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">7</label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option B</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">8</label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option C</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">9</label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option D</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">10</label></td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Right Answer</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">C</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td></td>
        <td colspan="2"><a href="http://localhost/bol25kids/admin_question.php?question=174706"><button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> &nbsp; Alter this question
        </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
 <tr rowspan="2"><td colspan="2"></td></tr>
        <tr>
 <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Question</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">नाग कुमार का दण्डक कौनसा है  ?</label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option A</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">तीसरा </label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option B</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">चौथा</label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option C</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">पांचवां</label></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Option D</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">छठा </label></td>
    </tr>
 <tr>
     <td><label class="control-label">Right Answer</label></td>
        <td><label class="control-label">A</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td></td>
        <td colspan="2"><a href="http://localhost/bol25kids/admin_question.php?question=174606"><button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> &nbsp; Alter this question
        </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: @Akshay I added the functionality you requested.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the `<input ...>` inside a `<form ...>`, you can just hit enter to go, no submit button needed.

```
<form action="#" id="gotoForm">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Go to ..." name="goto" id="goto">
</form>
```

Then attach the jQuery to the form to handle the submit-event. This saves you from having to decode key-codes, and saves you running an event handler for every keypress.

```
$("#gotoForm").on("submit", function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();
    showPage($("#goto").val());
}
```

Also, you'll need to refactor the click handler for the span, and extract the function so you can call that from the submit handler as well.

```
$('span').click(function(event) {
    showPage($(this).text());
});

function showPage(page){
    $('#tblData').find('tbody tr:has(td)').hide();
    var nBegin = (page - 1) * recordPerPage;
    var nEnd = page * recordPerPage - 1;
    for (var i = nBegin; i <= nEnd; i++) {
      $(tr[i]).show();
    }
  };
```